# Two foreign keys from one table

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, database-schema, erd

I am trying in following DB ERD that `User` creates a `Profile`. A user can see his followers as well as the profiles that users are following.

[image: Database ERD]

The problem is:

Both sections either "Followers" or "Following" are users not Profile

**Update:**
Is the following approach okay or in above diagram?

```
 SQL> Create table users(
  2  user_id number(5) primary key,
  3  reg_date date,
  4  name varchar2(50),
  5  password varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL> Create table Follow(
  2  follow_id number(5),
  3  following number(5) constraint User_fk references users(user_id),
  4  follower number(5) constraint User_fk1 references users(user_id));

Table created.
```

Please advise. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What do you mean by "reference ... foreign keys"? Only primary keys are referenced, you don't "reference" a foreign key. If you are asking if you can have two foreign keys in one table, each of them referencing primary keys in two different tables, then the answer is yes, absolutely. In your arrangement, why do you need table FOLLOW to reference table PROFILE?

Comment: A FK in some table references a PK/UNIQUE in some table. Please make clear for each FK exactly what column(s) in what table is referencing what column(s) in what table. Your writing is not clear, please use more words to express your 1st paragraph & point 1, and give details for point 2.

Comment: @mathguy I updated my question please advise which approach is better

Answer (score 1):

1. Should Profile be an entity/table separated from User, or should they be merged?

This depends on your requirements. If a user has just one profile (as on many sites, e.g. on this one), the profile doesn't need to be a separate entity. Then the question whether the following relationship should point to users or to profiles vanishes. If, however, a user can have more than one profile (which might be guessed from your FK `type_id`), let's say one for his sports and another for his musical interests, then two entities and tables are needed.

2. Should Follower point to User or to Profile?

In the case of just one User entity, `follower` and `following` must both point to User, as there is nothing else. This is your SQL solution.

In the case of a separate Profile entity, it's again up to your requirements. Should the follower follow the user as a whole, or is he just interested in a certain profile angle of the user? (Follow Jack, or follow Jack as a sportsman, but not as a musician.) In the first case, `following` points to the User, otherwise to the Profile.

Comment: The user has only one profile that is separate entity. Here "Follower" means Profile followers. I separated this profile entity to make it a totally separate module from users module